# Run script on ec2 instance terminate

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, window

I am creating an AMI. I want to know if you can run a script when you terminate Windows 2008 R2 instance. I know that you can run script when you shutdown and start an instance. But I need to run some scripts when you terminate an instance. Any help would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate is not a good practice to put scripts in.
If we compare it to physical computer then
`Start(AWS) = Push Button to start PC (Physical)`

`Shutdown(AWS) = Click Shut Down in Windows (Physical)`

`Terminate(AWS) = Pulling the plug (Physical)`

So can't run scripts from that instance or on AWS platform when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the most common answer here is to:

1. Set up an SQS queue
2. Set up an SNS topic that sends a message to the SQS on instance termination
3. Having something read the queue, parse out the instance name/id from the termination message and act accordingly

Unfortunately there's no shutdown equivalent to cloud-init yet.

This is a good guide for it: http://www.nuvolecomputing.com/2012/07/02/chef-node-de-registration-for-autoscaling-groups/